# Syntax error, unexpected '{' when using the Facebook PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook, flash, oauth, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to get my team's Flash project on Facebook, but I cannot get any of the PHP-SDK examples to work.  I've followed several examples, such as this new one on github ([here](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php)).  However, I keep getting a parse error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in
>   /home/content/r/a/s/rashomon/html/projects/facebook/test/hellomyflash/index.php
>   on line 36

I downloaded the latest PHP-SDK.  Here's my file structure:

```
.../hellomyflash/

   index.php

   src/base_facebook.php

   src/facebook.php

   src/fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt
```

The only two lines I changed in index.php are the appId and secret.

index.php :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright 2011 Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may
 * not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
 * a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
 * WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the
 * License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */

require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '###############',
  'secret' => '################################',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}

// This call will always work since we are fetching public data.
$naitik = $facebook->api('/naitik');

?>
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
  <head>
    <title>php-sdk</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #3b5998;
      }
      h1 a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>php-sdk</h1>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
    <?php else: ?>
      <div>
        Login using OAuth 2.0 handled by the PHP SDK:
        <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
      </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>PHP Session</h3>
    <pre><?php print_r($_SESSION); ?></pre>

    <?php if ($user): ?>
      <h3>You</h3>
      <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">

      <h3>Your User Object (/me)</h3>
      <pre><?php print_r($user_profile); ?></pre>
    <?php else: ?>
      <strong><em>You are not Connected.</em></strong>
    <?php endif ?>

    <h3>Public profile of Naitik</h3>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/naitik/picture">
    <?php echo $naitik['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I got the same "unexpected '{'" error when following [this](http://eagerfish.eu/example-facebook-iframe-app-using-graph-api-through-php-sdk/) example.

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: well what is `line 36` ? SO doesn't do line numbering for us

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your server is most likely running PHP4, the code provided is for PHP5.

PHP4 does not have try/catch blocks.

Comment: Precisely, line 36 is `  try {`.

Comment: That looks like it was the problem.  Now, I'm another problem.  The authentication request isn't firing.  Then, I get they grey iframe that says, "The website cannot display the page".  I'm using the official FB code from http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/.  Should I start a new thread for this?

Comment: Yes, please do, not as many people looking to help with already solved questions.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't want to spin off threads unnecessarily.  :)

Comment: UPDATE + EASIER SOLUTION : Facebook now has an "Auth Dialog" tab under "Settings".  You can use this page to do the user login/authentication without javascript or php - VERY quick and simple!  If you see a message at the bottom that says, "In order to use authenticated referrals, you must migrate your app to use the enhanced auth dialog on the advanced settings page", just follow the link, click "enable" next to "Enhanced Auth Dialog", and save your change.  Then, you can add the permissions you want to request.  Then, you're good to go!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you go in to "facebook.php" and "base_facebook.php", the close tags for php is missing,    " ?> " at the bottom of the page. I've heard that this caused problems for some, and it got fixed when they added close tags. You can try ;)

But after seeing the answer from the dude over me, that's probably the correct answer! :p